# Can cutting down on how much you eat really help with weight loss?

Tags: diet

I have reduced my daily intake by 50%, It's been over a month, but my weight remains the same. Can anyone explain to me why?

Answer (score 2):

#### You are not in a calorie deficit.

The neurobiology of weight loss is vastly complex. There are numerous mechanisms involved in your body that regulate the relationships between hunger, satiety, metabolism, and energy expenditure, and when these things are disordered, it can make weight loss extremely difficult. But there is one thing about weight loss that is very simple.

*Physics*.

The physics of weight loss is quite simple: an energy deficit will *always* lead to weight loss, and if you are not losing weight, you are not in an energy deficit. This is an incontrovertible fact of thermodynamics. So not only does eating less *help* with weight loss, eating less energy than you expend is quite literally *the only* way to lose weight, aside from cosmetic surgery like liposuction.

Now, as mentioned previously, the neurobiology is extremely complex, and likely explains why you think you should be losing weight but aren’t. The most likely reason is that you are probably just eating more than you think you are, and expending less energy than you think you are. This has been observed time and time again in observational research: people tend to grossly underestimate their intake and grossly overestimate their expenditure.